# PHP: What's wrong with my website log in code?

Tags: php

So I'm very new to PHP and I'm still learning. I just learned about superglobals and using POST, GET, SESSION, COOKIES etc. 
To test my current knowledge, I made a simple log in code. Where there are two pages, one for logging in, the other is the destination that can only be reached by logged in users. It's very simple, there is only one password "test pass" and it's checked through an if-statement. The username can be anything the user wants. I will obviously add more functionality to this project, like a sign up page, account info changing settings etc. But I can't do that without having my main code being solid. So my question is, security-wise, is this code okay? What would you do differently, and if there are non-security issues, I would also like to know.

Login Page:

```
<form method="post">
  Username: <br>
  <input type="text" name="user"> <br>
  Password: <br>
  <input type="password" name="pass"> <br>
  <button type="submit" name="signin">Sign In</button>
</form>

<?php


session_start();

  if (isset($_GET['logged']) && $_GET['logged'] == 'false'){
    session_destroy();
    header("Location: login.php");
  }

  if (isset($_POST['signin'])){ //form was submitted

    //username check
    if (!empty($_POST['user'])){ //username entered
      $_SESSION['user'] = htmlspecialchars($_POST['user']);
    } else { //no username entered
      echo "You must enter your username!";
    }

    //password check
    if (!empty($_POST['pass'])){ // a password was entered
      if ($_POST['pass'] == 'testpass' && !empty($_POST['user'])){ // the password was correct and a username was entered
        $_SESSION['logged'] = true; //user is logged in
        header("Location: loggedin.php");
      } else { // incorrect pass
        echo "Incorrect Password!";
      }
    } else { //no pass entered
      echo "You must enter a password!";
    }
  }  

?>
```

Logged in page:

```
<html>
<head>
  <?php session_start(); 
  if (!$_SESSION['logged']){
    header("Location: login.php");
  } ?>
  <title>Welcome <?php echo $_SESSION['user'] . "!";?></title>
</head>
<body>
  <a href="login.php?logged=false">Sign Out</a>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sidenote: [you're outputting before header](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php)

Comment: to answer your question: no. what I'd do differently? Everything. Starting with prepared statements, right up to using `password_hash()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is okay for single user. You can improve security by adding `md5()` function. 
eg: `$_POST['pass']=md5('testpass');`  and `$_SESSION['user']=md5($_POST['user']);`

If you want code for multiple user. Add mysql (database).

Comment: I wouldn't use md5() anymore.  It is a weak hash, md5() and sha1() are outdated.  password_hash() in >5.5 is ideal.  You could also use crypt() directly in <5.5 with sha256/sha512 for stronger hashes with salts.

Answer (score 0):

Are you going to be using a database to store users and other data?  It'd be hard to evaluate the security of this if you're later going to be using a database.

In that case, you'd need to use prepared statements when querying the database and hashing when storing the passwords like Fred said.  Prepared statements add protection against SQL injections which are very important to keep under control.

Another form of injection you need to worry about is script injection, or cross-site scripting (XSS).  This is when you print user input back.  You have added some protection for this using `htmlspecialchars()` on `$_SESSION['user']` but you can do more, look more into it.